# Web grid control supporting collapsible grouped columns

Tags: web, grid

I'm looking for a web grid control that supports collapsible column groups, to address my needs:

- large number of columns, up to 30 or even more
- columns could be logically grouped, on average 3-5 columns per group
- columns could be toggled per group, to increase readability

An ideal target is Excel-like style with "+"/"-" button to collapse/expand column groups, allowing user to focus on columns of interest at a time.

Please suggest promising candidates fitting the needs, any recommendation is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it help you, but it's possible to implement this with TGrid http://grid.tesseris.com

This control is not supporting column groups but, it supports custom column header templates and dynamic column reconfiguration. So you can add some controls to headers and add some code to dynamically add/remove columns.